# How to fix HP Officejet 7210 scanning in Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, preview, scanning

I have a HP Officejet 7210 printer/scanner. I used to use Preview to scan, using `File/Import from scanner`. However, since upgrading to Mountain Lion, the option is greyed out.

Previously, the option had a sub menu where I had to select 'Include Networked Devices'. Afterwards, the printer, which is connected via Ethernet, showed up and I could scan. Now, there is no submenu anymore.

Image Capture also says no scanners are connected, and going through printers/scanners in preferences and clicking 'open scanner' shows a dialog with the 'scan' button greyed out.

Does anyone know how I can make HP Officejet 7210 scanning work again, either with Preview, or with some other software?

Comment: My HP printer scanner combo is constantly crashing since ML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suddenly, the printer now appears directly in the menu of Preview. I have no idea what changed. So the takeaway is that 'Include Networked Devices' doesn't exist anymore and is always on. If your printer doesn't show, close the programs, turn off your printer, and try again. It might show up later.